# Android voice detection

Tags: android, microphone, voice-detection

I'm developing an Android application (only for Samsung Galaxy S4 at the moment) where I need to continuously monitor sounds from microphone in order to detect voices, and possibly how many people are speaking (I don't want to recognise what the people are saying, just detect that someone is speaking). How can I do it? The only way is through MediaRecord getMaxAmplitude()? But then How can I understand how many people are speaking? Thanks

Comment: Instead of getting how many Peoples are speaking from Sound, You can get the number of people in the call.

Comment: Sorry maybe I didn't explain the problem properly, I don't want to detect the number of people during a call but I want to detect how many people are with me in the same room.

Comment: Identifying the number of speakers from a recording could be difficult even for a human being, so I doubt that you'll find an easy solution to this. Try looking for research papers to see if and how other people have gone about this task.